# Maven. Creating a library with dependecies accessable to users of library

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a library that acts as a wrapper for selenium. I want the user of my library to be able to access not only my library, but also all of it's dependencies (e.g. selenium).

Here is part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <descriptorRefs>-->
<!--                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>-->
<!--                    </descriptorRefs>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                            <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
                            <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The first part is working, but not the latter. My Library (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9Ml.jpg) imports fine but I can't import (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGsJl.jpg) any of it's dependencies.

I've tried copying and unpacking dependencies as well as jar-with-dependencies but to no avail.

This isn't something I have done before and really have no idea what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this question is previously  answered. What you want is called a fat jar or uber jar.

Comment: Here is an article for you: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Took a while to get it set up and working, and if I build it through maven rather than intellij it seems to work. any idea why or do you have to do some extra setup to get a jar-with-dependecies.jar for artifacts?